# How would I overwrite the return address of a kernel function?

Tags: x86, stack, overwrite

I have a process running that calls sleep(), and I would like to overwrite sleep()'s return address, so that when it returns it will execute my code instead.  The process doing the overwriting is run next with no protections or isolation.  Where is that return address stored and how would I change it, with asm perhaps?

Comment: `Where is that return address stored` - on stack as usual. The problem is not how to overwrite it but how to find where it is and how to get there (OS will not allow you access not your memory).

Comment: What happens if you compile with optimizations and your `sleep` function is inlined?

Answer (score 0):

You can't overwrite a kernel function's return address from user-mode in the x86 architecture - the processor switches stack when doing an inter-privileged control transfer that uses it.
And depending of the [mechanism used to enter the kernel-mode](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html), the address may not even be on the stack.

As usual, all the details in the [Intel Software Developer's Manual 3](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.html).

---

That said, most of the user-mode functions are wrapper around the system calls - so they are not, yet, kernel functions and as such you could "simply" poison the return address on the stack to steer the control flow as you please (à la [Return Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming)).
Granted that your hooking code gets a chance to execute before the hooked function returns.

However processes are isolated, I don't know what you mean with

> The process doing the overwriting is run next with no protections or isolation.

but you need to have the payload in the hooked process, no matter what.

Depending on how you placed a payload there in the first place, it may be easier to just change the call to the target function into a call to a procedure of yours that calls the original function along with executing the payload (instead of dealing with a transient structure like the stack).
Bottom of the line, if you are going to patch the executable to place a payload in its code section, patch the call as well.

If your, unstated, intention is to hijack an imported/dynamically linked function then that calls for a specific question itself, with a better context than the one you provided here.